# How can I add items to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have this code :

```
$http(req).then(function success(response) {
    // $scope.table = { fields: [1,2] };
    $scope.table = { fields: [] };
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        // add elements from response to $scope.table
    }
});
```

The question is: how do I add elements to my variable `$scope.table`?
As we know, variables in JavaScript are not strongly-typed. I can't find any documentation that explains how to manage a type generated by something like this `{ ID: [] }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the variable `$scope.table` is an [*Object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) which has an array property (at key) *fields*. With that array, use [array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elements to the end of the array.

e.g.

```
$http(req).then(function success(response) {
// $scope.table = { fields: [1,2] };
$scope.table = { fields: [] };
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    // add elements from response to $scope.table
    $scope.table.fields.push(response[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the explanation, your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have anything to do with JS being strongly-typed or not.
Simply access the `fields array` using the notion below:

`$scope.table.fields.push(i);`

Put it inside your `for` loop.